# "File as" not working for Contacts

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, bugs, google-contacts

Many contact management tools (such as Google Contacts or Microsoft People) have a field called "File As", which allows to save a contact using a nickname, while keeping the first and last names hidden, just in case you forget who they really are.

It would be really useful, but it [doesn't work at all](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26262/how-to-force-contacts-to-respect-file-as-or-nickname-field-for-sorting-and#comment283340_214337) on Android. While the contacts are displayed correctly on the [web app](https://contacts.google.com/), Android applications like WhatsApp still display my contacts by first and last name.

**Is this a Google/Microsoft problem or is it caused by android/WhatsApp itself?** Is there any workaround to make it work (at least for WhatsApp)?

It's ok for me if it involves coding or installing an unofficial version of any application, but it would mean a lot to me if I could fix this issue for me.

---

Looking inside the [Android Developers reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactNameColumns) I couldn't even find any information about the "File As" field, so I wouldn't know where to start!

Comment: Apps can query the address book of your device. How they display the different address fields is decided by the developer of the app. Therefore if Whatsapp does not show the contacts the way you like then this is a problem of Whatsapp.

Comment: @Robert thanks for your response. Is there any way I can make WhatsApp think that the _file as_ field is the actual contact's name? As said, altering the app or the address book is ok, as long as the contacts on my Google Account remain the same...

Comment: Related: [How can I make WhatsApp use the "File As" field?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250567/44325)