# How can I make WhatsApp use the "File As" field?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

In the Google Contacts app, I can enter a value in the "File As" field in a contact's details. I can search for contacts using this field (both in the Android app and on the web https://contacts.google.com ).

I would like to make WhatsApp use the "File As" field when displaying the name of a contact. I would also like it to display that user in the search results when I search for that contact using the "File As" value. How can I do that?

It would also be useful to be able to search in WhatsApp for contacts using the "Nickname", "Phonetic first", "Phonetic middle", and "Phonetic last" fields. Right now, WhatsApp only seems to search the "Prefix", "First name", "Middle name", "Surname", and "Suffix" fields.

Comment: Without probably some hacky/modded apps, I don't think this is possible without relying on WhatsApp developers because of how it is currently coded inside the app...

Comment: Related for more general case: ["File as" not working for Contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/238735/44325)