# To add a “File As” field to your Google Contacts, you can follow these steps:

Tags: contacts, google

RESOLVED: Google Contacts WILL default to a 'File As' field as the main Contact name.
You just have to create the Custom field labeled File As. Follow these steps and you can change the names to whatever you'd like, AND keep all the real information in Contact records. Very handy! Thanks

**To add a “File As” field to your Google Contacts, you can follow these steps:**

1. Open Google Contacts on your computer.
2. Click on the contact you want to edit.
3. Click on the **Edit** button (pencil icon) in the top right corner of the screen.
4. Scroll down to the **Show More** link, click on it.
5. Select **'Add Custom Field'**
6. Type in what you want to file the contact as, then (MOST IMPORTANTLY) type File As in the Label field.
7. Click on the Save button to save your changes.

That's it. Now why it's not already a field, nor in the Help section, who knows? But as of November 2023 it still works.

Best wishes. Have an amazing day!

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Looks like you're trying to post an answer to [How can I force Google Contacts to respect "File as" (or "NickName") field for sorting and display?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26262/44325) If so, I have unprotected the question so you can post the answer there now. Thanks, and happy contributing :)